# Elixir/Phoenix scan directory for directories

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to scan a given directory and need to receive only directories back. This way returns all files and folders in a given `dir`:

```
dir = "/Users/user/releases/"
folders = 
    File.ls(dir)
    |> elem(1)
```

Is it possible to filter `folders` to keep only directories, and no individual files? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter the list of files/directories using `File.dir?/1` to get only directories back. Since `File.ls!/1` returns just the file name, and not the full path, you'll also need to join `dir` with the file name before passing it to `File.dir?/1`:

```
iex(1)> dir = "."
"."
iex(2)> File.ls!(dir) |> Enum.filter(&File.dir?(Path.join(dir, &1)))
["config", "lib", "test"]
iex(3)> dir = "test"
"test"
iex(4)> File.ls!(dir) |> Enum.filter(&File.dir?(Path.join(dir, &1)))
["foo"]
```

Comment: Hey @Dogbert, Thanks for your solution,  I've tried and in works for a current directory, but if i pass another directory "File.ls!(dir) |> Enum.filter(&File.dir?/1)" it just returns  empty list. Should I change File.dir? to also path a directory?

Comment: @Ilya ah, I forgot to consider that. I've updated my answer with a solution that should work for any directory.

Comment: Thank you @Dogbert now everything works. It didn't work because at File.dir? it didn't know the full path to the directories?

Comment: Yes, without `Path.join`, it would check for the existence of the directory with that name in the current folder always, no matter the value of `dir`.

Comment: `File.cd!(dir, fn -> File.ls! |> Enum.filter(&File.dir?/1) end)` looks more expressive to me.